# Is it possible in highchart to put percentage in the middle of the column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highchart to create a column chart as below, but I have difficulty in order to put percentage in the column, I want to put the percentage in the middle of the column as figure below. kindly your suggestion.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/dhitiacahya/po8j7sub/7/

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
    },
    labels: {
        items: [{
            html: 'Total fruit consumption',
            style: {
                left: '50px',
                top: '18px',
                color: ( // theme
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                ) || 'black'
            }
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'John',
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
    },]
});
```

[image]

Comment: Without your code, how would you expect us to help you? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i have added the codes sir,  https://jsfiddle.net/dhitiacahya/po8j7sub/7/

Comment: Your question should contain the code. I'm quite sure you got this, and you just ignored it? `Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.`

Comment: appreciate your reminder @JamesZ. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally after few hours searching and try code, i found the way to make a chart i was desire.

Solution :

1. i added a new y point as a spline chart
2. put zoomType: xy in the chart object.
3. make an array as an Array so that you can secondary yAxis.

here is the link:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Combination chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
    },
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}%',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Percentage',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    },{
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
      
        }],
   
    labels: {
        items: [{
            html: 'Total fruit consumption',
            style: {
                left: '50px',
                top: '18px',
                color: ( // theme
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                ) || 'black'
            }
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000],
       
    }, {
        type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
        name: 'John',
        data: [2000000, 2000000, 2000000, 2000000, 2000000]
    },
    {
        name: 'Percentage',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [92, 97, 93, 98, 105],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' °%'
        },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter:function() {
                        return this.y+ '%';
            }
        }
    }]
});

chart.series[2].options.color = "#";
chart.series[2].update(chart.series[2].options);
```

Here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/dhitiacahya/Lymxq9aj/80/

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. Please [remember accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add the plotOptions shown below

```
    plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.y + "%";
            }
        }
    },
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    column: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: it will show all data label, what i want to accomplish is that only one datalabel as percentage which is the value from the division number of the 2 column in the charts

Comment: check this jsfiddle  link may it helps u

https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/y03qjbhk/1/